# How to import a local grammar in tree-sitter node?

Tags: typescript, grammar, treesitter

I am currently trying to import my own created grammar in a typescript node project in the following way:

```
import Parser = require('tree-sitter');
import Language = require('tree-sitter-own');
```

This throws the error:

```
Cannot find module 'tree-sitter-own' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

In the package file under dependencies it is imported as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
        "tree-sitter-own": "file:../../tree-sitter-own"
}
```

If I check the `node_modules` folder it got correctly installed and copied over. There are however no type definition files in the tree-sitter grammar. How can you correctly import a grammar in node or how can you correctly add type declarations so typescript can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to build your grammar using [WASM](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter/blob/master/lib/binding_web/README.md) and then require it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).